# Chaining "siblings" and "not" method

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, siblings

I'm currently trying to chain the .siblings and .not method:

```
$(nextBanner).siblings(".banner").not(".active").hide();
```

But it doesn't work – does anyone know how to target a set of siblings and exclude the ones that have a particular class?

You can watch my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/timkl/56Mqg/25/

Comment: `$(nextBanner).siblings(".banner").not(".active").hide();` is correct.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
$(nextBanner).siblings(".banner:not(.active)").hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$(prevBanner).siblings(".banner:not(this)").hide();
// and
$(nextBanner).siblings(".banner:not(this)").hide();
```

also you could do a `$(".banner").hide()` and then `$(nextBanner).show();`

Comment: This is the best answer to the question.

Answer (score 3):

you simply forgot to remove the `active`-class. i modified you example just a tiny bit (and i don't use `siblings()` at all) so it works: http://jsfiddle.net/56Mqg/27/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.banner').hide();
$(prevBanner).show().addClass("active");
```

and

```
$('.banner').hide();
$(nextBanner).show().addClass("active");
```

Your code have few flaws which I have corrected in your fiddle. Take a look at it.

**Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/56Mqg/29/)**

Comment: This doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: @RightSaidFred - I agree, but I modified OP's code in the fiddle do you mind to take a look at the demo and remove down vote?